# python continously scanning directory

Tags: python, directory, monitoring, scanning

I know that there are some other feeds about it, but none of them that I found has my issue:

I have a python script that is scanning continously X directories (today it's 11) for a new file, takes it to another directory where another script/program analyses/processes it. Either the source or destination can require an FTP / SFTP / SMB connection. The python script is a main that launchs X processes (with `multiprocessing.Process`), so every source can be scanned seperatly.

My issue is : sometimes, without warning and without any process stopped, some source directory aren't being scanned anymore (there are files in it, but not being listed, so not taken). Sometimes it's a FTP, sometimes a Windows directory accessed by samba, sometimes an SFTP.

When I restart the service, it works well again.

Any idea ?

Also, python is not an obligation, we totally can swap to other languages, but for the moment we don't have the time to rebuild an entire application.

**edit**:

`connect = Libs.connection.Connection(self.config, server)`

opens the connection via FTP/SFP/SMB like so

```
def __init__(self, config, server):
    self.config = config
    self.extensions = config['supported']['extensions']
    self.directories = config['directories']
    self.local = ROOT_DIR + '/' + self.directories['app'] + '/' + self.directories['tmp']
    self.source = server
    self.env = self.source['environment']
    self.ftp = ftplib.FTP()
    source, dir = self.buildftp()
    self.ftp.connect(source, self.source['port'])
    self.ftp.login(self.source['login'], self.source['password'])
    self.ftp.set_pasv(config['ftp']['passif'])
    self.ftp.cwd(dir)
```

each class has a different listing method

`while True:
    files = connect.listdir()`

and for example FTP.listdir

```
def listdir(self, dirftp = None):
    lines, filesarr, folders = [], [], []
    if dirftp is None:
        self.ftp.dir(lines.append)
    else:
        self.ftp.dir(dirftp, lines.append)
    for line in lines:
        tmparr = line.split()
        if tmparr[0][0] == 'd':
            name = tmparr[-1]
            if name != '.' and name != '..':
                folders.append(name)
        else:
            name = tmparr[-1]
            filename, fileextension = os.path.splitext(name)
            if fileextension.lower() in self.extensions:
                filesarr.append(name)

    return filesarr
```

I have to say that we have another python script using exactly the same method to scan permanently another FTP directory, and it never fails.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in your code. If only there was a way for you to show it to us...

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Maybe a connection loss if accessed over the network?

Comment: Sorry, I edited to add some code